# C# Como renomear MUITOS arquivos mais rapidamente ou ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: c#, enumerable, numeração

Então pessoal, eu estou criando aqui um programinha para renomear arquivos, o código que fiz está muito lento e só renomeia um arquivo por vez, e não conseguir criar um código para renomear todos de uma vez até porque são números distintos e não é em sequência o que talvez facilitaria.

Código;

```
        DirectoryInfo pasta = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);

        FileInfo[] adxs1 = pasta.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo names in adxs1)
        { File.Move(names.FullName, names.FullName.ToString().Replace("old_00079", "new_00098")); }

        FileInfo[] adxs2 = pasta.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo names in adxs2)
        { File.Move(names.FullName, names.FullName.ToString().Replace("old_00091", "new_00105")); }
```

Então, a sequência é essa, e são MUITOS arquivos mais de 1000 rsrs.
O que queria saber de vocês é se eu posso, por exemplo, renomear todos ou uma parte de uma só vez, mesmo que seja números distintos?

Comment: Pode se ti ver um padrão. Só não consigo entender porque pegar os arquivos de novo se já pegou uma vez, e porque não fazer tudo em um *loop* só. Fora isto, poderia fazer assincronamente,l se bem que 1000 deve ser bem rápido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar paralelismo:

```
var movesSimultaneos = 2;
var moves = new List<Task>();

foreach (var filePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath))
{
    var move = new Task(() =>
    {
        File.Move(filePath, filePath.ToString().Replace("old_00079", "new_00098"));
    }, TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness);
    move.Start();

    moves.Add(move);

    if (moves.Count >= movesSimultaneos)
    {
        Task.WaitAll(moves.ToArray());
        moves.Clear();
    }
}

Task.WaitAll(moves.ToArray());
```

[Traduzi daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18991870/1314276).

#### Adendo

[`File.MoveTo()` tem um desempenho melhor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18987514/1314276).